# Gnome 3 and multiple monitors - parts of the screens staying black

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, radeon

I've got a Radeon HD 7870, and Ubuntu 14.04; it's running fine with software drivers, but I'm trying to get some acceleration running.

Ideally I would get both my monitors running (both attached by DVI, one has a resolution of 1920x1080, the other of 1280x1024).
It used to work fine under 13.10 (but I'm not sure anymore whether I was using gnome3 there or unity), but all tries to get this running properly under 14.04 and gnome3 so far were unsuccessful.

There's these really weird issues:
When I use fglrx, and configure my secondary monitor, the right part of the primary monitor and the whole secondary monitor stay black; only the big "2" in white font in the red rectangle identifying the screen, and the mousecursor is shown. If I move any window there, it simply isn't shown, the screen stays blank except for the mousecursor. Because the display itself shows something I'm suspecting this is somehow a gnome3 issue. Even interaction seems to still work in the black area, at least the mouse cursor changes for a region where there should be a link in a browser, and the region is clickable and reacts normally. So "just" the rendering seems to be affected. I tried doing the switch using both the AMD Catalyst Control Center and the "Display" option from the System Settings, there is no difference in the outcome.

Is there some way to tell gnome to properly use the whole first display and the second monitor? Using a different window manager or something?

An "analog" screenshot of the situation (a "real" screenshot won't show the problem - it shows what would be the expected output, namely a fully drawn screen without a black bar):
[image: black bar]

When I deactivate a monitor (so that only one monitor is enabled) - then, in addition to the black bar on the right side, I occasionally (e.g. after the switch itself) get strange, seemingly random, flickering bar effects.

Any hints? Or what more information do I need to provide to fix this? Using software drivers is not really an option since only one screen works with these, and CPU usage is quite high...

Edit: Switched back to unity now, there everything works normally with fglrx - no regions occluded by black bars or anything... I guess I'm going to have to stick with that for the moment. What a pity, I really had started to like gnome 3...